# Is there a way to not overwrite the modifications done to entities when regenerating them?

Tags: jhipster

I've recently joined a project that uses jHipster. The data model is still actively evolving and because jHipster is used for entity generation the developers are reluctant to make changes to the entity classes like using all the JPA annotations not generated by jHipster.

We're considering using dbUnit or similar testing framework to write integration tests to make sure cascades, etc. are not lost.

Is there a way to indicate to jHipster that I want to keep some parts of the code unchanged?

If no, is there a better recommended workflow than having to go through diff and reapply the changes removed during generation?

Comment: Tests are certainly a good idea. Some people run  generator on a git branch and select adequate merging strategy to keep manual modifications.